# In Cassandra 3.x, is there a way to set a limit on the cluster usage for each keyspace?

Tags: cassandra

I am currently working on setting up a Cassandra cluster that will be used by different applications each with their own keyspace (in a multi-tenancy fashion). 
So I was wondering if I could limitate the usage of my cluster for each keyspace individually. 
For example, if keyspace1 is using 65% of the cluster resources, every new request on that keyspace would be put in a queue so it doesn't impact requests on other keyspaces.

I know I can get statistics on each keyspace using `nodetool cfstats` but I don't know how to take counter measures.
Cluster resources is also a term to define as it can be total CPU usage, JVM heap usage, or proportion of write/read on each keyspace on the cluster at instant t.

Also, if you have strategies to avoid entering into this kind of situation, I'm glad to hear about it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Cassandra doesn't have such functionality. That's why it's recommended to setup separate clusters to isolate from noisy neighbors...

Theoretically you can do this on Docker/Kubernetes/... but it could take a lot of resources to build something working reliably.